# How do I upload multiple images with paperclip but also have an additional field for some?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am uploading multiple images (4 file fields) using paperclip, which is working fine just fine and dandy but I want to also attach a description to 3 of the 4 file fields. So far I have created a model called "Asset" which has the following:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project 
  has_attached_file :asset
end
```

My project model is aware of the assets and has_many assets:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :presence => true

  has_many :assets
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets
end
```

And in my _form.html.haml I am creating 4 fields like so:

```
- number = 0
= f.fields_for :assets do |asset|
  %ul.fields
    %li= asset.label :asset, "File ##{number += 1 }"
    %li= asset.file_field :asset
```

And of course my projects_controller.rb contains the following to build the 4 fields:

```
def new
  @project = Project.new
  4.times { @project.assets.build }
end
```

My questions are, where is the best place to put this "description" for each of the fields, the assets or projects? My second one is how do I not render a description field for the last one in the loop but do in fact render a description field for the first 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. in the Asset model. I'm assuming the description is of the image.
2. a quick way would be to just put

   ```
   ...
   %li= asset.file_field :asset
   - if number < 4  
     %li = asset.label :description  
     %li = asset.text_field :description
   ```